# Date formatting exception unparseable date

Tags: java

I am trying to format dates entered by my application user using SimpleDateFormat but I always get an error:

```
 01/28/2014java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/28/2014"
```

The code I am using to format the date is as follows:

```
    Date rDate, dDate;
    String Date1 = request.getParameter("Date1");       
    String Date2 = request.getParameter("Date2");

    //Here the date get display for example as 01/29/2014 (i.e. MM/DD/YYYY)
    System.out.println("Date1::   "+ Date1);
    System.out.println("Date2::   "+ Date2);

    SimpleDateFormat parseRDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat parseDDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        //#########Crashes in the next two lines#########...
        rDate = (Date)parseRDate.parse(Date1);
        dDate = (Date)parseDDate.parse(Date2);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can someone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Why did you post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21175710/642706) under two titles inside of an hour?

Comment: @BasilBourque Please review answers below I was instructed by Reimeus to issue a new question as based on the replies I received the problem expanded. Please compare the 2 questions

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the `DateFormat` pattern to your input `String`

```
SimpleDateFormat parseRDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

> Any idea how I can convert the format from MM/dd/YYYY to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

All you need to do is use a separate `SimpleDateFormat` instance for formatting

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(output.format(date1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I am trying to do here is to convert the date format from MM/dd/yyyy as entered by the user to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. The code I am using above I found on the web as example of formatting date, but I guess I misunderstood it here. So any idea how I can convert the format from MM/dd/YYYY to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Comment: You can use another `SimpleDateFormat` with a different pattern to format the output String, using the pattern you have already

Comment: OK just to make sure that I am not missing anything here I am trying to save those fields in DB as timestamps, so I am using this as field definition in my Entitiy class: @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @Column(name="DDATE", nullable=false, unique=false) private Date dDate; the problem is that each of the app users machine can have different date format, so I must save to the DB in one fixed format despite of the users date format. So I want to convert the date to the app date format then save it...makes sense?

Comment: You would need to determine the users `Locale` for the input `DateFormat`. It looks like you're using a web interface or servlet. You could use [ServletRequest.html#getLocale](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale())

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `Date1` is of the form `MM/dd/yyyy`... but you're trying to *parse* it with a format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

The pattern you parse to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor has to match the format of the data itself. (What did you think you were specifying in the constructor?)

Note that the code you've provided isn't doing and *formatting* at all - just parsing.

You should also work out which time zone you're interested in, and which `Locale`. Personally I think it's clearer to specify both of those explicitly - even if you want the system default ones.

(If you're doing any significant amount of date/time work, you should also consider using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time), which is a much more pleasant date/time API. I'd also consider more useful exception handling, and following Java naming conventions...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I am trying to do here is to convert the date format from MM/dd/yyyy as entered by the user to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. The code I am using above I found on the web as example of formatting date, but I guess I misunderstood it here. So any idea how I can convert the format from MM/dd/YYYY to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Comment: Well you need one formatter for parsing (using the input format) and one formatter for formatting (using the output format). I'm not sure it's useful to have a full date/time output when the input is only a date though. Why do you need this? I hope you're not including it in a SQL statement...

Comment: I am saving both fields in DB as timestamps so yes I need date and time in each field to save them as timestamps, and that's one of the reasons why I am formatting them as well

Comment: @MChan: That's not a good idea. Use a PreparedStatement and pass the values to the database as Java.sql.Timestamp values (or whatever is appropriate). You do *not* need a string for that.

Comment: I do save the fields in DB as timestamp, actually here is on field definition for example in the Entitiy class: @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DDATE", nullable=false, unique=false)
private Date dDate; the problem is that each of the app users machine can have different date format, so I must save to the DB in one fixed format despite of the users date format. So I want to convert the date to the app date format then save it...makes sense?

Comment: @MChan: No, it doesn't - because string formatting shouldn't be involved in the transfer to the database at all. As you've said, you've got a field of type `Date` - why would you need to convert that to a string format? At the storage level, there's no such thing as fixing it "in one fixed format" - the underlying storage will be in a binary format, and the JDBC driver is responsible for transmitting the `Date` to the database. That *could* end up with a textual intermediate form, but in most cases there'd be no need for that.

Comment: I must make a String variable to read the user input from the JSP, I can't just read Date from there as far as I know, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @MChan: That's the *parsing* part. Yes, you'll probably need to parse the data from text. But then you shouldn't need to format it to send it to the database. (You may need to format it again when you display it to the user later, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 1):

You specify the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in the constructor and then accept a completely different format (`MM/dd/yyyy`) as input. You need to make the actual format match the expected format.

Examine the following (for comparison):

```
Date rDate, dDate;
SimpleDateFormat parseRDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat parseDDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
try {
    rDate = (Date)parseRDate.parse("2014-01-28 12:22:22");
    dDate = (Date)parseDDate.parse("01/28/2014");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The string passed to the constructor is what tells `SimpleDateFormat` how to read the input you give it later.