# Issue with Java Date format

Tags: java, date

Inside my application I allow my users to enter some dates, which I should save in DB. Now since some of my application users are located in different locations worldwide and each have their own date/time format, I thought of accepting any date format from them, then change those formats to a fixed format which I can then save in DB.

Yet my problem now is that I getting an error when trying to change date fromat from that entered by the user to my application format, below is the code I am currently working with

1. Entity field:

   ```
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
   @Column(name="DDATE", nullable=false, unique=false) 
   private Date dDate;
   ```
2. Controller code that save in DB:

   ```
   Date rDate, dDate;
   String Date1 = request.getParameter("Date1");       
   String Date2 = request.getParameter("Date2");

   //Here the date get display for example as 01/29/2014 (i.e. MM/DD/YYYY)
   System.out.println("Date1::   "+ Date1);
   System.out.println("Date2::   "+ Date2);

   SimpleDateFormat parseRDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   SimpleDateFormat parseDDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   try {
       //#########Crashes in the next two lines#########...
       rDate = (Date)parseRDate.parse(Date1);
       dDate = (Date)parseDDate.parse(Date2);

   } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

So can someone please suggest how I can format any date entered by my users to the application static date format?

Thanks

Comment: The expected format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) doesn't match the actual value (`01/29/2014`), it's simply unparasable.  Try using `MM/dd/yyyy` as the format instead...

Comment: There is no universal "Figure out what the user meant" date parsing function.  You need to examine the user's locale and choose the expected format.  How is java supposed to guess if 01/02/2013 is Jan 2nd or Feb 1st?

Comment: @Affe what if I separated the date to MM and DD and YYYY Encode / Decode date in other words, will this allow to work with any possible date format the user enters? and if yes is there a Java method to Encode / Decode date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 as universal date for everyone.

If anyone can enter any string, you'll never know if 08/12/75 is December 8th or August 12th

From the wikipedia:

```
Date and time (current at page generation)
expressed according to ISO 8601:
Date:   2014-01-11
Combined date and time in UTC:  2014-01-11T12:21:05+00:00
2014-01-11T12:21Z
Week:   2014-W02
Date with week number:  2014-W02-6
Ordinal date:   2014-011
```

Comment: answer edited with link to the standard and examples

Comment: Note to the reader: The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes that supplant the old legacy date-time classes utilize these ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.